# How to find(figure out) pixelated part of image

Tags: image, blur, vision

I want to find pixelated part of image.
for example,

[image: example image]

[image]

then, I want to find "AREA" of pixelation by bounding box. 
At first, I think that R-CNN might be helpful, but later after that, I think using only traditional method is also possible for this problem such as finding difference of image entropy.. etc..

Are there any method for solving this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't rush to accept my answer... leave it a few days and you'll probably get something better but if you accept, few people will bother answering... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thinking aloud really... the pixellated areas are regions of solid colour so they will have a very low variance and standard deviation, so, we can try some experiments with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

If we take your image, and go to greyscale, then calculate the standard deviation in a 7x7 area around each pixel, then invert so that the areas with lowest standard deviation are bright, then normalise to the full black-white range and threshold the very brightest pixels:

```
convert p.png -colorspace gray -statistic standarddeviation 7x7  -negate -normalize -threshold 99.99% result.png
```

[image]

Changing the numbers a bit:

```
convert p.png -colorspace gray -statistic standarddeviation 3x3  -negate -normalize -threshold 99.9% result.png
```

[image]